# Why coping/updating list are very slow in OCaml?

Tags: arrays, performance, linked-list, ocaml

So basically I am using list in my ocaml program, and originally it goes like this way:

```
val mutable ll : string list = []
.....

ll <- ll@[(foo ar1 ar2)]
```

Then when testing on relatively big data set (over 50k), my program just running too slow.

I was thinking that it is because there is a **whole list copy** process in the above code, (each time when `ll <- ll@[]`)

So I changed my code in this way:

```
ll <- (foo ar1 ar2)::ll   (* extend the head for N times *)
.....
List.rev ll
```

However, to my surprise, it seems that there is not explicit performance improvement..

Then I tried array like this:

```
let arr = Array.make len "" in 
  arr.(counter) <- (foo ar1 ar2);
  counter := !counter + 1
.....
Array.to_list arr
```

In my understanding, it should be better than the first methods, however, probably because there might be other low performance bugs in my code, I just still can not explicitly improve the performance even if I changed my `list` operation code in the above methods..

So here is my question, theoretically, in the above three strategies, which one has the best performance?

I should be able to do some experiments myself, but as a more general question, is there any better performance strategy in dealing with related issue?

Comment: “So I changed my code in this way:” Either you explain it wrong, and you were doing N calls to `List.rev`, as Jeffrey appears to be assuming. Or you did a wrong manipular and you were not testing this code (did the compiler perhaps emit an error and let you execute the previous version?). `ll <- x::ll` is constant-time and very cheap.

Comment: Hi @PascalCuoq , yes, I explained it wrong, I extended the head for N times then did one time `List.rev`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an element at the end of the list is linear in the length of the list, and it does require copying the whole list. If you build up a whole list this way, you get quadratic complexity.

The same is true if you add to the end by reversing the list, then adding to the front, then reversing again. Reversing a list requires copying the list.

The usual technique is to build up the list in reverse order *completely*, then reverse once when you're done. This has only linear complexity overall. Adding to the front of a list is a constant-time operation.

If you don't need to increase the size of your array (which requires a copy of the array), using an array as you show also has linear complexity.

There could be other slow spots in your code that are masking your changes to this one spot.

In my opinion, if you're not mostly done coding, you should think just about basic complexity (linear, n log n, quadratic etc.). If you really need to worry about performance you can refine things later. You don't want to end up tossing out code that you spent a lot of time tweaking.

Comment: Hello Jeffrey, thank you a lot for your answer! Sorry I explained it wrong, I extended the head for N times then did one time List.rev and I have tested it, it works correctly with very low performance...It should some other parts of my code..